# Problem displaying data in .NET MAUI when using CollectionView

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, xamarin, maui

I'm having difficulty displaying data in my .NET MAUI application. On my Feed page, I use a CollectionView control to display a collection of data from the ReceiptsViewModel class.I have a Receipt model and I expect data to be associated with this model and displayed in my CollectionView. However, despite the data collections being populated correctly and the properties in my Model and ReceiptsViewModel being correct, nothing is shown on the screen.

Feed:

```
public partial class Feed : ContentPage
{
    public Feed(ReceiptsViewModel rvm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = rvm;
    }
}
```

Receipt model:

```
namespace Messenger.Model
{
    public class Receipt
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Photo_URL { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, object> Ingredients { get; set; }
        public string Cooking { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }

        public Receipt(string name, string photo_URL, string description, Dictionary<string, object> ingredients, string cooking, string author)
        {
            Name = name;
            Photo_URL = photo_URL;
            Description = description;
            Ingredients = ingredients;
            Cooking = cooking;
            Author = author;
        }
    }
}
```

ReceiptsViewModel:

```
namespace Messenger.ViewModel
{
    public partial class ReceiptsViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        ObservableCollection<Receipt> receipts;

        [ObservableProperty]
        string receipt_name = "";

        [ObservableProperty]
        string receipt_description = "";

        [ObservableProperty]
        string receipt_author = "";

        [ObservableProperty]
        string receipt_cooking = "";

        [ObservableProperty]
        string receipt_photo = "";

        [ObservableProperty]
        Dictionary<string, object> recepient_ingredients;

        public ReceiptsViewModel()
        {
            Receipts = new ObservableCollection<Receipt>();
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        void Add()
        {
            var receipt = new Receipt(Receipt_name, Receipt_photo, Receipt_description, Recepient_ingredients, Receipt_cooking, Receipt_author);

            Receipts.Add(receipt);
        }
    }
}
```

Feed.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Messenger.Feed"
             Title="Feed"
             xmlns:viewmodel ="clr-namespace:Messenger.ViewModel"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:ReceiptsViewModel">

    <Grid RowDefinitions="100, Auto, *"
          ColumnDefinitions=".75*, .25*">
        <Label Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
               Text="Receipts"
               FontSize="40"
               BackgroundColor="AntiqueWhite"
               x:Name="l"/>
        <Button Text="+"
                HorizontalOptions="End"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                BackgroundColor="Black"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Margin="15"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                Command="{Binding AddCommand}"/>
        <CollectionView Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,15,0,0"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Receipts}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Padding="0,5">
                        <Frame Margin="3,0,5,3" BorderColor="Black">
                            <HorizontalStackLayout>
                                <Image MaximumHeightRequest="100" MaximumWidthRequest="100" Source="dish.jpg"/>
                                <VerticalStackLayout Margin="20,0,0,0" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Receipt_name}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Receipt_description}" TextColor="LightSlateGray" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
                                </VerticalStackLayout>
                            </HorizontalStackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

(no)Result image:
[[image: Result]

I expext that i will have ObservableCollection receipts`s data visualised correct

I tried to do collections of names and etc but nothing helped, i`m not so expirienced so i would like to ask this question here.

Comment: the `Receipt` object does not have a property named `Receipt_name`.  It does have a property named `Name`

Comment: @Jason Yes it does, but how can i use it ?

Comment: Correct your binding expression to use the correct property name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **CollectionView.ItemTemplate**'s binding context is the **ItemSource's item**. So you should binding the **property of the Receipt** class instead of the property of the ViewModel. Such as:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
<Label Text="{Binding Description}" TextColor="LightSlateGray" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
```

For more information, you can refer to the [official collectionview sample](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/tree/main/8.0/UserInterface/Views/CollectionViewDemos).